# Location Field as exposed Filter in Drupal View

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, drupal-exposed-filter

I'm creating a Drupal View and i need to expose a location field.

I'm setting the coordinates like arguments  using this format " 9.781755, -75.872394" but i can't get the view works.

Is there some special input format for this kind of field?

[image]
[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the location field type that you 're using. Is this WKT format?
Why not using the nid in the contextual filter? You 'll have the same results.